# ProxyPassMatch is giving 404 Not found in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, redhat, proxy

I have a Virtual host configuration file as follows:

```
<VirtualHost  *:8086>
        ProxyRequests off
        ServerName  localhost
        ProxyPassMatch ^/App/rest/performancetest/executetest/(.*)/(.*)$  http://somedomain.com/$5/$6
</VirtualHost>
```

When I hit the URL, `this_server_ip:8086/App/rest/performancetest/executetest/x/y` I get 404 Not found. But Just for testing purpose if I use

`ProxyPass /App/rest/performancetest/executetest/x/y  http://somedomain.com/x/y` instead of ProxyPassMatch in the configuration, I get the page I am expecting on the browser. Now What is wrong with the way I am using ProxyPassMatch? I really want to match last two parts of the URL. So using ProxyPassMatch is a must for me. I am using apache 2.2.3 on a Redhat server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go re-read the ProxyPassMatch documentation. Your current directive maps `/App/rest/performancetest/executetest/<something>/<somethingelse>` to `http://somedomain.com` whereas you want to map it to `http://somedomain.com/something/somethingelse/`

I'm not really sure why you are using ProxyPassMatch, would not the following work for you?

```
ProxyPass /App/rest/performancetest/executetest/  http://somedomain.com/
ProxyPassReverse /App/rest/performancetest/executetest/  http://somedomain.com/
```

Note. Always match trailing slashes.

Edit after comment. If you want to use the last to parts of the URLs, then you need to use them :-)

```
ProxyPassMatch /App/rest/performancetest/executetest/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ http://somedomain.com/$1/$2/
ProxyPassReverse /App/rest/performancetest/executetest/  http://somedomain.com/
```

The ProxyPassReverse may not been needed. It depends on your application.

Comment: To make it simple, I didn't provide /something/somethingelse. I have updated my post. Please check. I have read the documentation, don't know why it is not working for me.

Comment: Do I need to do anything else to use ProxyPassMatch?

Comment: @sachin bhardwaj I've updated my answer to account for your requirement